# Swift Fatal Error ( Crashes on Start )

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am getting the error

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

and this only happens when I put this line in

```
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if wall.position.x == 0 {
        score = score + 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }


}
}
```

The line that the error says it is on is "if wall.posistion.x == 0 {" I mean where it says the Thread Error "**EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0**)". I'm trying to create a scoring so when the wall passes through that x point the score goes up 1

Whole code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var movingGround: CSMovingGround!
var hero: CSHero!
var cloudGenerator: CSCloudGenerator!
var wallGenerator: CSWallGenerator!
var wall: CSWall!
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var score: Int = 0
var isStarted = false

var heroCategory: UInt32 = 1<<1
var wallCategory: UInt32 = 1<<2
var groundCategory: UInt32 = 1<<2




override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    /*
    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background.png")
    let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture, size: view.frame.size)
    backgroundImage.position = view.center
    addChild(backgroundImage)
    */



    // add ground
    movingGround = CSMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, kCSGroundHeight))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)

    self.addChild(movingGround)

    // add hero
    hero = CSHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    hero.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = heroCategory | wallCategory
    hero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory | groundCategory
    self.addChild(hero)
    hero.breathe()


    // add cloud generator
    cloudGenerator = CSCloudGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    cloudGenerator.position = view.center
    addChild(cloudGenerator)
    cloudGenerator.populate(7)
    cloudGenerator.startGeneratingWithSpawnTime(5)

    // add wall generator

    wallGenerator = CSWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    wallGenerator.position = view.center
    wallGenerator.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect : wallGenerator.frame)
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory

    self.addChild(wallGenerator)


    let ground1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 20))
    ground1.position = view.center
    ground1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground1.size)
    ground1.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
    ground1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    self.addChild(ground1)

    let ground2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 20))
    ground2.position = CGPointMake(284, 98)
    ground2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground2.size)
    ground2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
    ground2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    self.addChild(ground2)


    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    scoreLabel.fontName = "score"
    scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 275)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)


}



func start() {
    isStarted = true
    hero.stop()
    hero.startRunning()
    movingGround.start()

    wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(1)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if !isStarted {
        start()
    } else {
        hero.flip()
    }


}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(heroCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(wallCategory)) != 0 {
        wallGenerator.removeFromParent()
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
    }
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if wall.position.x < 70 {
        score++
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }


}
}


import Foundation
```

import SpriteKit

class CSWall: SKSpriteNode {

```
let WALL_WIDTH: CGFloat = 30.0
let WALL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50.0
let WALL_COLOR = UIColor.blackColor()

override init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: WALL_COLOR, size: CGSizeMake(WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT))
    startMoving()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func startMoving() {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: 1)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
}


}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `wall` variable and show what if anything you've done to initialize it?

Comment: Yeah, you never set the value of wall anywhere in your code. I don't know what a CSWall is, but it definitely needs to be set to something if you expect it to be anything but nil. You need to figure out how to get a CSWall and set self.wall's value – assumedly using CSWallGenerator but that's all dependent on your implementation.

Comment: @Dare unfortunately for me I'm very new to coding games / iOS Apps. Been trying to learn, I'll mess around and see what I can do! Also CSWall is the wall that CSWallGenerator is generating randomly!

Comment: @Dare I have added the CSWall if that helps or if you can give me any suggestions! :)

Comment: It may be true that CSWallGenerator is generating random CSWalls, but according to the compiler, that CSWall you named wall actually isn't anything at all. Your job at this point is figuring out where you need to actually set that property otherwise you're just trying to pull data from a void.

Comment: @Dare Well the game is kind of like the game "Flappy Bird" and I'm trying to make it so they get a point every time the "hero" passes one of the "walls" without colliding with it!

Comment: @Dare would I be setting that property in the GameScene?

Answer (score 0):

So the error seems to be pretty confident that you are trying to access properties of a nil value. wall.position.x probably isn't initialized. You can check for nil and do nothing if your value doesn't exist but you probably need to figure out why it wasn't initialized in the first place because it seems important.

```
if let wallPosition = wall.position.x {
     if (wallPosition == 0){
         score ++
         scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
     }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about initializing the wall? I'll put edit my code above to add all of it! I'm trying to get it so the "CSWall" (wallGenerator is generating the randoms walls) and when they reach x: 70 it makes a + 1 point on the score label.